# Have different brightness for different workspaces

Tags: workspaces

I would like to have different brightness for different workspaces on the same monitor in Ubuntu. Is this possible on gnome? (Using Ubuntu 19.04 as of now)

This is because I would like to have dark windows open in one workspace and light ones open in another workspace.

Comment: Multiple monitor or single?

Comment: It is the same monitor

Comment: not possible as a feature of ubuntu but definitely scriptable behavior.

Comment: Please add this information about your monitor to your question by editing it. A question, not the comments, should contain all relevant information.